# React Native. While component props changed, one depended element re-renders but another - not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

`CardItem` receives the `cardIsLocked` prop, which changes frequently and depends on user actions.

`TouchableOpacity`, that affected by this prop, reflects all app state correctly all the time. I can or can't press on it accordingly to my expectations. That is why I know that its `disabled` prop re-renders well. But prop `style` of top `View` component - doesn't.

So, all interaction works as demanded but styles not re-renders. How could this difference be possible during usage of the same prop `cardIsLocked`?

Thanks for ideas.

```js
const CardItem = (props) => {
    const card = props.card;
    const cardIsLocked = props.cardIsLocked;
    const handler = props.handler.bind(this, { card });

    return (
        <View style={cardIsLocked        //  <-- not causes re-renders
                     ? styles.cardLocked
                     : styles.cardActive}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                disabled={cardIsLocked}  //  <-- causes re-renders
                style={styles.innerCardSpace}
                onPress={handler}
            >
                <View style={styles.card}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{card.cardName}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
};
export default CardItem;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    cardActive: {
        padding: 1,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 3,
        maxWidth: 30,
        minWidth: 30,
        height: 50,
        borderColor: "#00ee00",
    },
    cardLocked: {
        padding: 1,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 3,
        maxWidth: 30,
        minWidth: 30,
        height: 50,
        borderColor: "#black",
    },

    innerCardSpace: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignContent: "center",
        flexDirection: "column",
        margin: 1,
    },
    card: {
        height: 26,
        width: 46,
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#white",
    },

    text: { fontWeight: "700", fontSize: 10 },
});
```

Comment: Try to debug prop use useEffect hook.
e.g
`useEffect(() => {
  console.log(cardIsLocked);
  console.log(cardIsLocked ? styles.cardLocked : styles.cardActive);
}, [cardIsLocked]);`
And add here the behavior.

Comment: Wery simple and helpful approach, thanks) So, in the console the behavior of my CardItems looks as demanded. I see, that style changes every time correctly but not reflects on screen.

Comment: You're welcome. :)

I'm not sure if the way u are receiving props, can change some behavior in the reactivity of your component causing this no-render.

Try it: Descontruct your props as `const { card, cardIsLocked } = props`. This is the common way used to catch only the property from an object.

Comment: Maybe assigning your props to a new variable/constat, makes your component lose the "subscription to updates" from your props.

Comment: As I see, there is no difference, deconstruct props or not. It looks like React does it's work well, but Raect Native or Expo doesn't.

Comment: In the case of lost subscription this problem would be observed for both components, as I understand. And yes, I tried this variant yet)))

Comment: I got it. So, I notice that your color names have preceded with`#`. Maybe it's the problem.
Because when you use color names e.g: "black", "green", don't need `#` at the start of the name, only colors in RGB e.g `#000` `#00ff00`;
And because of this mistake, I guess React keeps the last color set. In your case it is `"#00ee00"`

Comment: If it works, It explains, why the test with `useEffect` works and in the `style` attribute, won't 
Actually works, but de color isn't set in the wrong format...

Comment: You are absolut genius!!! That was a bug.  Can't believe. Thank you, friend!

Comment: You're welcome, my friend.
Could you accept my answer below as correct? 
Just for me earning some points here in the community 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to formalize the answer.

The error is the `#` at the beginning of the color's name.

The `#` must be used when declaring code RGB like `#eeff00`. For colors declared as names the `#` isn't necessary

So the re-rendering is occurring. But the problem is when any attribute of style has an unacceptable format, React doesn't apply it, and tries to keep the last identical attribute or will do nothing.

### The code fixed

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
cardActive: {
    padding: 1,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 3,
    maxWidth: 30,
    minWidth: 30,
    height: 50,
    borderColor: "#00ee00",
},
cardLocked: {
    padding: 1,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 3,
    maxWidth: 30,
    minWidth: 30,
    height: 50,
    borderColor: "black",
},

innerCardSpace: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignContent: "center",
    flexDirection: "column",
    margin: 1,
},
card: {
    height: 26,
    width: 46,
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "white",
},

text: { fontWeight: "700", fontSize: 10 },
});
```